# jQuery 1.7.2 target all the browsers except IE below 8.9v

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I think this could be achieved with a simple function. But Im quite new to jQuery and this is a great way to get started how functions work.

**I want to run a script for all the browsers for except IE 6,7,8 and all the versions of v8 such as 8.1, 8.2 and so on until 8.999. Why doesn't this work**

```
function IeVersion678Check(){
     if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8.99) {
         return true;
     }

}


if (!IeVersion678Check) {
  //run my script
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using conditional comments instead...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

$.browser was removed in jQuery 1.9.

From the jQuery Help page:  [jquery $.browser Help page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

> Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell. Im using 1.7.2

Comment: It looks like when using 1.7.2 $.browser returns IE 11 as mozilla instead of msie. I'm not sure what happens when you actually use IE 8 and lower. If you have an older version of IE you can try to view the $.browser object to see what is returned: console.log($.browser);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input. This worked with jQuery 1.7.2

```
function IeVersion678Check(){
     if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8.9) {
        return true;
     }
}

if (IeVersion678Check() != true) {
    //run script
}
```